# How to deal with the error variable lengths differ

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a panel data covering several individuals over a five year period and I want to do a 2SLS estimation using the plm package. My Instrumental Variables are the first lag of the endogenous variables, `S` and `S_active`. When I run the second stage IV regression I have the following errors:

```
  variable lengths differ (found for 'S_hat')
```

Please, can someone help me out on how to resolve this error?

Apparently, by making use of the first lag of the S and S_active variables in the first stage regression, I will lose observations for one year for each panel. As such I understand the error to mean that the fitted values of my endogenous variables will have a shorter length compared to the original data. And that's why my second stage IV regressions throws up that error.
I have googled how to deal with this error and came across quite similar questions here. But none has particularly addressed my specific situation.

I tried another suggested solution (ie. to add the fitted values to the original data) but got another error:

```
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9196, 7192
```

The following is how my code looks like:

```
library(bootstrap)
library(AER)
library(systemfit) 
library(sandwich) 
library(lmtest) 
library(boot) 
library(laeken)
library(smoothmest)
library(glm2) 
library(tidyverse)
library(foreign)
library(plm)


data_09=read.csv("panel2009.csv")
attach(data_09)

table(is.na(data_09)) 

  FALSE 
1480556

#First Stage. Run plm, regressing S on exogenous idependent variables including the IV, lag(S)
firstpan=plm(S~ act + plm::lag(S) + S_active + C_tot, data=data_09, na.action = na.exclude, index = c("individual","year"), method = "within", effect = "twoways")
         summary((firstpan))    
  
#First Stage. Run plm, regressing S_active on exogenous idependent variables including the IV, lag(S_active)
      
secondpan=plm(S_active ~act + act*plm::lag(towater) + S + C_tot, data=data_09, na.action = na.exclude, index = c("individual","year"), method = "within", effect = "twoways")
           summary((secondpan)) 

#Collect fitted values and add them to data 
S_hat=fitted(firstpan)
S_active_hat=fitted(secondpan)    

#Run the standard 2SLS using S_hat=fitted and S_active_hat as instruments
iv=ivreg(Y ~ act+ S + S_active + C_tot|act + S_hat +S_active_hat + C_tot,data=data_09, na.action=na.exclude)
     summary(iv)
```

```
Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'S_hat')
```

The first stage regressions run succesfully, but the second-stage IV regessions throws up the error: Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'S_hat')

Comment: Does `length(S_hat)` equal `length(S_active_hat)` and `nrow(data_09)`? The error suggests they don't. I can't recall if fitted values correctly accounts or `na.exclude`. Have you tried `S_hat=predict(firstpan)` and `S_active_hat=predict(secondpan)`  instead?

Comment: ```length(S_hat)``` and ```length(S_active_hat)``` are equal ie. ```7192.``` But they are not expected to be equal to  ```nrow(data_09)``` which is ```9196.``` This is because the use of the lag eliminates all observations for year 5 of all panels. And I have tried the predict option but I get the same error. Any further suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Ah well that’s the issue then. You need pad S_hat and S_active_hat with NAs so they equal nrow(data_09).